# Android: How to open a new full screen fragment from a fragment

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I would like to open a new full screen view (layout) from a fragment without have to create a new activity.

I know how to do it creating a new activity but I read you better "always" use multiple fragments, not multiple activities for your full project so I am following that "rule"

You can check the images attached to explain the situation I would like to reproduce. As you can see, from a fragment with a listview, it open a new full screen view. Tapping the back button in the action back, you go back to the main with navigation, toolbar and the list.

I am using xamarin but a suggestion using java will work too for me. I just need to understand the concept of how to do this and what kind of controls do they used.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I know how to do it creating a new activity but I read you better "always" use multiple fragments, not multiple activities for your full project so I am following that "rule"" - Not true, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @PPartisan in my case, I would like to use fragments to make it easier to transfer data among fragments. Do you have any comment about how to reproduce this behaviour